# Back end is not working magento Version 2.3.4

Tags: magento2, php

Any solution for below magento back end error

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /home/domains/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php on line 591

Comment: do you run Magento provision commands?

Answer (score 1):

If you getting sodium related error then you can use below both way.
First Solution ->
I have just solved the issue, you don't need sodium any more, just follow this
goto vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php
comment code from line 165 to 167 like this

```
//if (extension_loaded('sodium')) {
// return self::HASH_VERSION_ARGON2ID13;
// }
```

it will start working.

Second Solution ->

Even I got the same notice message when I try to login into Magento2 admin panel, after upgrading Magento2 from 2.3.1 to 2.3.2

For me, it got solved after installing PHP version 7.2 and installing the php7.2-sodium extension.

Or

Update your current user which gets the error when you log in with it.
    UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxxNewPassword', 256), ':xxxxxxxx:1') WHERE username = 'admin';

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I m also facing the same issue.

For me, It's fixed after installing PHP version 7.2 and installing the php7.2-sodium extension

Try this solution and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I randomly got trapped into this bug on Magento Cloud as well. The fix was to remove the admin user having issues with and create a new one and try.

Hope this will help you.